# Can I develop SharePoint 2013 add-in from different machine in domain?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have SharePoint Foundation 2013 installed on a server. I want to do the development using My machine. I have Visual Studio 2015 installed, with Office tools. I can create an app and deploy it to office 365. But when i try to deploy to an on-premise server I get the following error;

Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in': The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

Comment: What are the authentication protocols configured on the SharePoint server?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this the below link. As per my understanding Office 365 uses https and local used http. sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html. Also have you created a dns entry in your local server (host file) please check.

Comment: please check if in IIS settings for the site you have enabled the option for Anonymous Authentication and all other authentication options are disabled. Also please check your event logs as well.